# Convert simple line of batch file to bash

Tags: bash, batch-file

To run the program `zandronum.exe` with the file `brutalv21.pk3`, the instructions for windows give this piece of batch file code:

```
@echo off 
start zandronum.exe -file brutalv21.pk3
```

But I downloaded `zandronum` for Linux. What is the equivalent in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is simple:

```
./filename -Arguments
```

---

So, you have to write:

```
./zandronum -file brutalv21.pk3
```

Answer (score -1):

windows programs won't just run under linux you'll need wine to run them. as far as I've heard ubuntu made running windows programs with wine pretty seamless

Comment: Did you read `But I downloaded zandronum for Linux` in the question?